# UIWebView, enter a password

Tags: objective-c, ios, uiwebview

I want to enter a password in a webpage I load in an UIWebView. The password is a string, and I want to enter the password and hit a button in the page, automatically when the View loads.

Any help?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you're using a UIWebView, I assume you're loading some web service into that WebView. Why not build your login system into the web service? You could even just use HTTP Basic Auth.

If you're managing the passwords within your cocoa app, then I would probably implement a UIAlertView with a UITextField asking for the password. When the user presses Login you can validate the password and then load your web service in your UIWebView.

If you're managing the passwords in a database on the website then you'd build an html/js/php/mysql login form and load it in the UIWebView first.

**Update**

I'd go with the first option and display your own login form using cocoa controls like the UIAlertView with 2 UITextFields. You can then save the username and password using the keychain services and submit them every time the users launches the app or the web session expires.

If you want to try this method I'd suggest having a look at the [ASIHTTPRequest](http://allseeing-i.com/ASIHTTPRequest/How-to-use) framework. In particular ASIFormDataRequest which let's you easily send a form with the correct fields.

```
- (void)login
{
    ASIFormDataRequest *request = [ASIFormDataRequest requestWithURL:url];

    // Change these values to the ones in NSUserDefaults and the KeyChain
    [request setPostValue:@"Joe" forKey:@"username"];
    [request setPostValue:@"Secret" forKey:@"password"];

    [request setDelegate:self];
    [request startAsynchronous];
}

- (void)requestFinished:(ASIHTTPRequest *)request
{
    // Use when fetching text data
    NSString *responseString = [request responseString];

    // Use when fetching binary data.
    NSData *responseData = [request responseData];
}

- (void)requestFailed:(ASIHTTPRequest *)request
{
   NSError *error = [request error];
}
```

Comment: The site I am loading is not hosted by me. The password and username are earlier entered in an UITextField, and stored in the NSUserdefaults. That is because of the saving conveniance and the fact that I have to use them elsewhere. I am just loading the page in the UIWebView.

Comment: @Hidde, does the website require a username and password? I guess what I'm trying to get at is what is it that you're trying to protect with this login form. Especially if the site is not your own?

Comment: The site is: http://leerling.degoudsewaarden.nl/. What I want to do, is log in with the username and password the user has stored in the app, to show him/her the page which is behind the password. The user could also log in himself, but I want to make the app easier to work with, by making it log in automatically.

Comment: So you want to override the login form with you're own one and submit the values yourself....what happens if the user enters the wrong username or password? I suspect they'll end up seeing the websites login form instead of yours along with an error message. Is this ok?

Comment: Thanks! I'll have a go at this, thanks for the long answer! +1

Answer (score 1):

Just an idea : you could try to add some javascript to the page before displaying it in the webview and use the ONLOAD event to fill the password field and post the form.

To do so you have 2 solutions :

- Use the stringByEvaluatingJavaScriptFromString instance method of [UIWebView](http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#documentation/uikit/reference/UIWebView_Class/Reference/Reference.html) , you could evaluate your javascript in the webViewDidFinishLoad delegate method for example. You will find an example here : http://iphoneincubator.com/blog/windows-views/how-to-inject-javascript-functions-into-a-uiwebview
- Or if for some reason you can't use this solution in your context you can always download the HTML using NSURLConnection, and then edit the string to insert your javascript. Then load the WebView using loadHTMLString:baseURL:

Comment: Hoe can I add JavaScript to a page? If I could, that would be the answer :D

Comment: I edited my answer to add some explanations, hope this solve your problem.

Comment: I will look into that, and try it. I'll mark the answer if it works! Thanks!

Comment: You might be interested in this related answer: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4881175/uiwebview-load-remote-html-page-with-local-images-and-javascript-files