# Font face usage in mobile native application

Tags: android, ios, css, html, cordova

```
@font-face {
  font-family: "Frodo Simplified Italic";
  src: url("../resources/FrodoSimplified_It.ttf");
}
```

A HTML5 application that loads in an iframe of a webview uses the above CSS statement. The fonts specified in the statement are made available in the application. I mean the ttf file is stored under the resources of the application. For example, in iOS it would be stored in the Resources folder of the application XCode project.

Now, will the `src` attribute request the server to fetch the fonts ttf file, even if it was made available to the app locally or will it use the local fonts?

I need the PhoneGap application to use the local ttf files on iOS and Android platforms.

Comment: Anywhere a href or src property is loading a file there will be an HTTP request sent.  That source rule will load the provided file from the provided filepath assuming the filepath is correct.

Answer (score 0):

Look at [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4881175/uiwebview-load-remote-html-page-with-local-images-and-javascript-files). The guy loads a remote html and uses local images and scripts.